# sequelize check constraint on multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a check constraint using `Sequelize` across multiple columns but I'm stumped.

My existing table is this:

```
create table public.testTable (
    isA bool NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
    isB bool NOT NULL DEFAULT true  
)
```

I want to create a check constraint with `Sequelize` so that it matches this DDL:

```
alter table public.testTable
add constraint bothCannotBeFalse check ( not (isA is false and isB is false) )
```

This is what I'd like to use:

```
queryInterface.addConstraint('testTable', {
    name: 'bothCannotBeFalse',
    type: 'check',
    where: {
        // it's expecting a column here, but I need to check BOTH columns
        // ???
    }
})
```

Is there a way to put a CHECK expression inside of WHERE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
where: {
  [Op.ne]: {
    isA: false,
    isB: false
  }
}
```